# How to get the structure of JSON in scala

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark

I have a lot of JSON files which are not structured and I want to get a deeper element and all the element to get to it.

For example :

```
{
"menu": {
    "id": "file",
    "popup": {
        "menuitem": {
                  "module"{
                      "-vdsr": "New",
                      "-sdst": "Open",
                      "-mpoi": "Close" }
        ...
    }
}
```

In this case the result would be :

```
menu.popup.menuitem.module.-vdsr
menu.popup.menuitem.module.-sdst
menu.popup.menuitem.module.-mpoi
```

I tried `Jackson` and `Json4s` and they are efficient to go the last value but, I don't see how I can get the whole structure.

I want this to run a job with apache spark on very huge JSON files and the structure will be very complex for each. I also tried sparkSQL but if I don't know the entire structure I can't get it.

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking to do is essentially a [tree traversal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal) of an object, where JSON objects are considered nodes with named branches and other JSON types are considered leaves.  There are many ways to do this.  You might consider making a recursive function that explores the entire tree.  Here is an example that works in `PlayJson`, but it shouldn't be very different in other libraries:

```
import play.api.libs.json._
def unfold(json: JsValue): Seq[String] = json match {
    case JsObject(kvps) => kvps.flatMap {
        case (key, value) => unfold(value).map(path => s"$key.$path")
    }
    case _ => Seq("")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The beauty of the new [DataFrame API](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame) is that it infers schema automatically, as you load the data.
It does so by doing a one-time pass over the whole data set.

I suggest that you load your json and then play with transformations and see what you can come up with. You can remove or select a subset of columns, filter rows, aggregate, map over them, anything really.

E.g:

```
// you can use globing to load multiple files
val jsonTbl = sqlContext.load("path to json file", "json")

// print the inferred schema
jsonTbl.printSchema

// now you can use the DataFrame API to transform the data set, e.g.
val outputTbl = jsonTbl
    .filter("menu.popup.menuitem.module.-vdsr = 'Some value'")
    .groupBy("menu.popup.menuitem.module.-vdsr").count
    .select("menu.popup.menuitem.module.-sdst", "other fields/columns")

outputTbl.show
```